# Why doesn't Lisp-Stat load with quicklisp under MacOS?

Tags: quicklisp, xlispstat

I'm relatively new to Common Lisp and Lisp-Stat. But I wanted to try it out and play around with it in my empirical social research.

Unfortunately installing LISP-Stat fails at building.

**My Setup**
SBCL 2.2.8 / Emacs 28.1 (Doom Emacs Config) / SLIME 2.27 / all on MacOS Monterey 12.6

**What I tried:**
`(ql:quickload :lisp-stat)`

**Error Message**

```
; Loading "lisp-stat"
;   caught 1 fatal ERROR condition
Building #P"/Users/stefan/common-lisp/cephes.cl/scipy-cephes/libmd.so"
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -Wno-unused-function -fno-builtin -fPIC -include cephes.h -include math.h   -c -o cbrt.o cbrt.c
```

**Full Backtrace**

```
 0: ((:METHOD NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD (T)) #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION ASDF/SESSION:SESSION-CACHE (1)> NIL) [fast-method]
 1: (SB-PCL::CALL-NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION ASDF/SESSION:SESSION-CACHE (1)> (NIL))
 2: (ASDF/SESSION:CALL-WITH-ASDF-SESSION #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA NIL :IN ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE) {1002DF771B}> :OVERRIDE NIL :KEY NIL :OVERRIDE-CACHE NIL :OVERRIDE-FORCING NIL)
 3: ((:METHOD ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE :AROUND (T T)) ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP "lisp-stat" :VERBOSE NIL) [fast-method]
 4: (ASDF/OPERATE:LOAD-SYSTEM "lisp-stat" :VERBOSE NIL)
 5: (QUICKLISP-CLIENT::CALL-WITH-MACROEXPAND-PROGRESS #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA NIL :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT::APPLY-LOAD-STRATEGY) {1002DF6AAB}>)
 6: (QUICKLISP-CLIENT::AUTOLOAD-SYSTEM-AND-DEPENDENCIES "lisp-stat" :PROMPT NIL)
 7: ((:METHOD QL-IMPL-UTIL::%CALL-WITH-QUIET-COMPILATION (T T)) #<unused argument> #<FUNCTION (FLET QUICKLISP-CLIENT::QL :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD) {1002CBDA4B}>) [fast-method]
 8: ((:METHOD QL-IMPL-UTIL::%CALL-WITH-QUIET-COMPILATION :AROUND (QL-IMPL:SBCL T)) #<QL-IMPL:SBCL {1004C6D5C3}> #<FUNCTION (FLET QUICKLISP-CLIENT::QL :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD) {1002CBDA4B}>) [fast-m..
 9: ((:METHOD QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD (T)) :LISP-STAT :PROMPT NIL :SILENT NIL :VERBOSE NIL) [fast-method]
10: (QL-DIST::CALL-WITH-CONSISTENT-DISTS #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA NIL :IN QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD) {1002CAF0CB}>)
11: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD :LISP-STAT) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
12: (EVAL (QUICKLISP-CLIENT:QUICKLOAD :LISP-STAT))
13: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SLYNK-MREPL::MREPL-EVAL-1))
14: (SLYNK::CALL-WITH-RETRY-RESTART "Retry SLY mREPL evaluation request." #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA NIL :IN SLYNK-MREPL::MREPL-EVAL-1) {1002CAE0AB}>)
      Locals:
        MSG = "Retry SLY mREPL evaluation request."
        THUNK = #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA () :IN SLYNK-MREPL::MREPL-EVAL-1) {1002CAE0AB}>
15: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SLYNK-MREPL::MREPL-EVAL-1))
16: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SLYNK::CALL-WITH-LISTENER))
17: (SLYNK::CALL-WITH-BINDINGS ((*PACKAGE* . #<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">) (*DEFAULT-PATHNAME-DEFAULTS* . #P"/Users/stefan/Nextcloud/Dokumente/eBooks/03_Technik/Programmieren/Lisp/") (*) (**) (***) (/) ...
18: (SLYNK-MREPL::MREPL-EVAL-1 #<SLYNK-MREPL::MREPL mrepl-1-1> "(ql:quickload :lisp-stat)")
19: (SLYNK-MREPL::MREPL-EVAL #<SLYNK-MREPL::MREPL mrepl-1-1> "(ql:quickload :lisp-stat)")
20: (SLYNK:PROCESS-REQUESTS NIL)
21: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SLYNK::SPAWN-CHANNEL-THREAD))
22: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SLYNK::SPAWN-CHANNEL-THREAD))
23: (SLYNK-SBCL::CALL-WITH-BREAK-HOOK #<FUNCTION SLYNK:SLYNK-DEBUGGER-HOOK> #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA NIL :IN SLYNK::SPAWN-CHANNEL-THREAD) {1001A9800B}>)
24: ((FLET SLYNK-BACKEND:CALL-WITH-DEBUGGER-HOOK :IN "/Users/stefan/.emacs.d/.local/elpa/sly-20220713.1433/slynk/backend/sbcl.lisp") #<FUNCTION SLYNK:SLYNK-DEBUGGER-HOOK> #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA NIL :IN SLYNK:..
25: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SLYNK::CALL-WITH-LISTENER))
26: (SLYNK::CALL-WITH-BINDINGS ((*PACKAGE* . #<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">) (*DEFAULT-PATHNAME-DEFAULTS* . #P"/Users/stefan/Nextcloud/Dokumente/eBooks/03_Technik/Programmieren/Lisp/") (*) (**) (***) (/) ...
27: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN SLYNK::SPAWN-CHANNEL-THREAD))
28: ((FLET SB-UNIX::BODY :IN SB-THREAD::RUN))
29: ((FLET "WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-11" :IN SB-THREAD::RUN))
30: ((FLET SB-UNIX::BODY :IN SB-THREAD::RUN))
31: ((FLET "WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-4" :IN SB-THREAD::RUN))
32: (SB-THREAD::RUN)
33: ("foreign function: call_into_lisp_")
34: ("foreign function: funcall1")
```

Why doesn't it compile? Any help very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Cephes had a problem where it wasn't loading on MacOS which has been corrected as of 2022-10-13.

Quicklisp has been a bit slow in updating as of late, and you don't want to use the version that's there now.  A better bet is to [get the source code](https://lisp-stat.dev/docs/contributing/code/#get-source-code) and then go from there.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Cloned the repositories, ran `(asdf:load-system :lisp-stat)` but still get the same error when building cephes. `Building #P"/Users/stefan/common-lisp/cephes.cl/scipy-cephes/libmd.so"
; Debugger entered on #<SB-POSIX:SYSCALL-ERROR {1003D652C3}>`

Comment: This is likely a problem in building the shared library on MacOS.  I don't have a darwin machine to test on, but what you need to do is figure out the flags to produce a shared library (it won't be .so, I believe they are .dylib extensions).